# Is it possible to have a single URL that points to two different pages?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have one url (/settings) that needs to point to two different pages depending on the users security on  login.  One page is the existing webforms page the other is a new MVC page.  Is this even possible?

Additional Info:
When the user is on either page the url needs to say website.com/settings

Solution:
Convinced the PM to change the requirements.

Comment: your action can return a different view based on some condition

Comment: You can always redirect the request or server different content, but... It's usually a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, *yes*.  You can do this several ways.

- Javascript
- Model View Controller (Controller)
- ASP.NET Web-Forms (Method)

It is often poor practice to do such an event, as it can expose data.  It is indeed possible:

*Javascript:*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($("#Account").val() != '') {
          $(".Url").attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
    }
});
```

Pretend `#Account` is a hidden field that is populated from your database.  If the field *is not* null then modify the `.Url` element to navigate to link. That approach for *Web-Forms* is the most simple.

*Web-Forms*:

```
protected void btnAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(User.IsInRole("Account"))
          Response.Redirect("~/Admin.aspx");

     else
          Response.Redirect("~/User.aspx");
}
```

That would use the default Windows Authentication for the domain, you could bend and contort to use the database to pull data.  An example, the *Model View Controller* would be similar as the `Controller` will simply handle that capability.

Hope this points in right direction.

Comment: Made this the answer for "It is often poor practice to do such an event, as it can expose data."  Instead of solving it I convinced the PM to change the requirement to something safer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a redirects based approach. Create a web page mapped to `/settings`, and have this code run on page load.

```
if(User.IsAdministrator()) //I take it you have some way of determining who is an Admin, so this is just example code
    {
    Response.Redirect("~/AdminSettings.aspx");
    }
else
    {
    Response.Redirect("~/UserSettings.aspx");
    }
```

Note that you'll need security on the Admin page to make sure a regular user can't just navigate directly there.